# Replace String with StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

How i can add a passStringBuilder() method creating a new method that does the same work as passString() does? I need this works with a StringBuilder object rather than a String object. Regards.

```
import intertech.MyDate;
public class PassByExperiment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyDate date = new MyDate(1, 20, 2008);
        System.out.println("Before passing an object " + date);
        passObject(date);

        System.out.println("After passing an object " + date);
        System.out.println("Before passing a primitive " +
        date.year);

        passPrimitive(date.year);
        System.out.println("After passing a primitive " +
        date.year);

        String x = date.toString();
        System.out.println("Before passing a String " + x);
        passString(x);
        System.out.println("After passing a String " + x); 
    }

    public static void passObject(MyDate d) {
        d.year = 2009;
    }

    public static void passPrimitive(int i) {
        i = 2010;
    }

    public static void passString(String s) 
    {
        int yearSlash = s.lastIndexOf('/');    
        s = s.substring(0, yearSlash + 1);
        s += "2012";

        System.out.println("New date string: " + s);
    }
}
```

This is what i tried:

```
public static void passStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb) {
   int yearSlashSB = sb.lastIndexOf('/');
   sb = sb.substring(0, yearSlashSB + 1);
   sb.append("2012");
   System.out.println("New date string: " + sb);
}
```

Comment: first *format* your code correctly

Comment: Check the JavaDoc for `StringBuilder`.  You'll find methods called  `lastIndexOf`, `delete` and `append` that you can use.

Comment: i tried but nothing if somebody have an example for me would be perfect ... btw this was my first post sorry for the first format code.

Comment: There are lots of example out there, you'll just need to search for them. And  "i tried but nothing" is pretty unlikely. Post what you've tried.

Comment: @Tom there is [mcve] attached already

Comment: @Tom I know, but just in case you're still interested..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a class which you can pass as any other Object:

```
public static void passStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb) {
    int yearSlash = sb.lastIndexOf("/");
    sb.delete(yearSlash + 1, sb.length());
    sb,append("2012");
    System.out.println("New date string: " + sb.toString());
}
```

`StringBuilder#substring` returns a `String` which is a substring, leaving `sb` as it was. You need to delete certain characters.

Basically, `StringBuilder` holds characters and lets you easily manipulate them. Later, it allows you to extract `String` from it. You can use `substring` or `toString`.

Since Java 8, it makes no sense to use it for concatenation as `String + String` is automatically changed to `StringBuilder` by Java.

Comment: Man you are the best, thanks for spending your time to answer me.

Answer (score -1):

Without the requirement being purely academic in nature, I'd suggest

```
public static void passStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb) {
    passString(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: How would this help in understanding passBy mechanism?

Comment: Op was asking on how to pass an object to method to perform the same functionality.  This is cleanest representation of the requirement unless it was an academic question, i..e how do I use StringBuilder.